# Org wide address isnot properly in the From address of the mail

Tags: singleemailmessage

After receiving mail still it shows FROM  address is "my email address(EG:****@gmail.com)" instead of org wide Email address.

Trying to set Like below:

- From address=Org wide email Address, 
  Remaining  email addresses => bcc

  ```
  public static void sendingEmailToMultipleSubscriber(List<GDPRSubscriber__c>gdprSubscriberEmailList,string SubId){
   List<string> toAddress = new List<string>();
  for(GDPRSubscriber__c gdprSub:gdprSubscriberEmailList){
      toAddress.add(gdprSub.Email__c);
  }
  ID whatID = SubId;
  OrgWideEmailAddress EA=[SELECT Id, Address, DisplayName FROM OrgWideEmailAddress WHERE DisplayName='************'];
  Contact cnt = [select id, Email from Contact where email != null limit 1];
  List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage> msgList= new List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage>();
  Messaging.SingleEmailMessage msg = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
  msg.setTemplateId( [select id from EmailTemplate where DeveloperName='***********'].id );
  msg.setWhatId(whatID);
  msg.setTargetObjectId(cnt.id);
  msg.setOrgWideEmailAddressId(EA.id);
  msg.setBccAddresses(toAddress);
  //msg.setToAddresses(toAddress);
  msgList.add(msg);
  Savepoint sp = Database.setSavepoint();
  Messaging.sendEmail(msgList); // Dummy email send
   Database.rollback(sp);

  List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage> msgListToBeSend = new List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage>();
  for(Messaging.SingleEmailMessage email:msgList) {
      Messaging.SingleEmailMessage emailToSend = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
      emailToSend.setBccAddresses(email.getBccAddresses());
      emailToSend.setPlainTextBody(email.getPlainTextBody());
      emailToSend.setHTMLBody(email.getHTMLBody());
      emailToSend.setSubject(email.getSubject());
      msgListToBeSend .add(emailToSend);
  }
  Messaging.sendEmail(msgListToBeSend);  
  }
  ```

Comment: Can you confirm the query `SELECT Id, Address, DisplayName FROM OrgWideEmailAddress WHERE DisplayName='************'` is actually returning just one record?  I would also put a `LIMIT 1` at the end the query as well

Comment: its returning only one record

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are performing a database rollback of your original send and then creating new email records that do not use your Org Wide Email Address. It is those records that are actually being sent.

I don't see any reason for using this structure. I recommend you remove the savepoint and rollback, along with all of the duplicated code, and perform one send of one list.

Comment: If I remove save point and rollback   ..  user will get 2 mails .. how to perform one send for one list.. can you please explain with small code snippets.its  really great

Comment: Your actual outgoing email messages _do not have an org wide email address set_. You need to restructure how you're building your outbound emails to make sure it gets set, one way or another. I would recommend _not_ using this rollback-based method to render an email template, that's what [`renderEmailTemplate()`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_email_outbound_messaging.htm?#apex_classes_email_outbound_messaging) is for.

Comment: Yes got it thanks